# Подключение проекта в проект в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-studio-2010

Как можно подключить файлы из одного проекта в другой в vs 2010?

Подключил .h, но не получается .cpp.
Сейчас получаю ошибку:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol...
```

UPD: важным является то что оба они являются исполняемыми, если бы нужно было подключить проект с либой, то я знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объединить два проекта в один solution - не означает, что проекты будут линковаться друг с другом. Если вы используете заголовочный (.h) файл в коде одного проекта, то **нужно подключить** в проект и файл-реализацию (.cpp), в котором реализованы классы, функции, статические переменные из заголовочного. **Подключить cpp-файл** в проект просто - достаточно в дерево проекта добавить существующий файл (например, просто перетащить файл из проводника или *add existing item* в контекстном меню).

Ошибка

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol...
```

означает, что сущность из заголовочного файла нигде не реализована. Например, объявлена функция, эта функция вызывается, но нигде не реализована.
Другой пример - объявление глобальной переменной с ключевым словом `extern` в заголовочном файле и отсутствие cpp-файла с определением этой глобальной переменной.

И еще. Поскольку два Ваших проекта - исполняемых файла используют одну и ту же функциональность, подумайте о том, чтобы вынести эту функциональность в отдельную библиотеку (подойдёт даже статическая lib-библиотека). Тем более, что либы вы умеете подключать.

Answer (score 0):

В настойках проекта `Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories ->` добавить в `Source Directories`.
По-моему это легко должно гуглиться и логически допетриваться)